# Fill the Image Sequence Ep. 2

Tags: mathematics, pattern, visual

Suggested by [Athin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/28719/athin), try & make another feasible puzzle for this series. Enjoy :D
The prologue also be revised more precisely.

---

This puzzle will provide several images. These images compose a sequence **with several grouping properties by the same objective feature, and one of them also makes the images get ordered additionally**.
Please try to identify what properties contained by this sequence, and answer the missing one.

**The answer should include an image, and a few reasons to illustrate why you pick the image.** Note that the answer may not be unique, but I'll try my best for the uniqueness.

---

**Question:**

[image]
$\to$
[image]
$\to$
[image]
$\to$
[image]
$\to$
[image]
$\to$
$(?)$

Comment: @Athin Hope this puzzle is better, wanna try to solve it? :D

Comment: FYI as I haven't commented or answered here so I didn't get pinged when you mentioned me ^^, but anyway yeah this feels much better, I haven't successfully solved it yet tho XD

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The next flag in the sequence is:

> [image]
>  The flag of **SOUTH KOREA**.

Why? For starters, note that the other flags belong to:

> BAHRAIN, MALDIVES, JORDAN, SINGAPORE and ISRAEL.
>  These are all countries in Asia. We are therefore looking for another country in Asia.

Next:

> Count the number of blocks of colour in each flag:
>  Bahrain = **2** (1 red, 1 white)
>  Maldives = **3** (1 green, 1 red, 1 white)
>  Jordan = **5** (1 black, 1 green, 1 red, 2 white)
>  Singapore = **8** (1 red, 7 white)
>  Israel = **13** (3 blue, 10 white)

These derived numbers are:

> Subsequent terms (after the initial two 1's) in the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

For the next term in the sequence, we are therefore looking for:

> A flag of an **Asian** country which is built up of **21** separate blocks of colour.
>
>  The South Korean flag satisfies this criterion (18 black, 1 blue, 1 red, 1 white).

Comment: Ubj qb lbh pbhag gra oybpxf bs juvgr pbybhe va gur Vfenryv synt? V frr fvk oybpxf va gur cbvagf bs gur fgne, bar oybpx va gur zvqqyr naq bar oybpx nebhaq gur fgne. V bayl znantr gb trg gb rvtug.

Comment: @jarnbjo The white is particularly hard to see against the background, I admit. But: rot13(gurer vf bar juvgr one ng gur gbc naq nabgure ng gur obggbz, nobir naq orybj gur oyhr fgevcf) :)  [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Israel#/media/File:Flag_of_Israel.svg)

Comment: Nu, bx. V gubhtug gur oyhr fgevcrf jrer qverpgyl ba gur rqtr bs gur synt.

Comment: @Stiv, You got it~ great observation :)